# trying to convert app.js to Typescript in Webstorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I am trying to convert the app.js in my NodeJS project in webstorm, to application.ts. I pasted the app.js code into a new file "application.ts" and replaced "app.js" with "application.ts" in the package.json file. The .ts file is not getting converted to .js even though the FileWatcher for typescript is on and works on every other file in the project. But when I "run" the project in Webstorm, I the project actually starts and runs "app.js" which I have obviously not deleted. Not sure, what other settings need to be changed to get this right. I plan on renaming application.ts to app.ts to suit the convention, once its successfully converted.

--Update--

Here's what my typescript filewatcher settings look like:

[image]

Comment: no surprise... Just changing the file extension doesn't normally change the file content, does it? And the typescript compiler run with file watcher converts typescript to javascript but not the vice versa... BTW, javascript is actually a valid typescript itself. Also, there is no way to run the typescrip application directly - it has to be transformed into javascript first

Comment: You can't run a TypeScript file so you should keep the app.js reference in your package.json instead of app.ts.

Comment: @Anzeo I realize that. I changed it to "application.js" not ".ts", hoping the compiler would make a .js out of it - thats not happening

Comment: @lena: My question is really more about webstorm. What do we need to get webstorm to "compile application.ts to application.js and then run that" INSTEAD OF "not compile application.ts and run app.js"

Comment: @EternallyCurious You're saying other ts files are compiled using WebStorm?

Comment: @Anzeo Yes - Everything except "application.ts". Can you provide a generic way to converting "app.js" to "app.ts" and then have it continuously compiled to .js by filewatchers.

Comment: @EternallyCurious normally, it should be picked up by the watcher. Check the settings (ctrl+alt+s) and navigate to the section with the file watchers, maybe it has been added to an ignore list by mistake?

Comment: @EternallyCurious please update the description and title - they are extremely misleading, as you need to 'compile application.ts to application.js and then run that' and NOT 'convert the app.js in my NodeJS project in webstorm, to application.ts'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file watcher is configured so that it merges all .ts files into a single main.js - see the arguments:

--out main.js

What is your application.ts - main application file? Would you like to generate a single .js for each .ts, or merge them? In the first case, you need to change the watcher arguments as follows:

--module commonjs --sourcemap $FileName$

then it will produce a singe js for each ts with name matching original ts file, with the format compatible with Node.js

To run the generated application.js instead of the original app.js from withihn WebStorm, you have to change the Node.js run configuration accordingly

By the way, if all you need is renaming 'app' to 'application', just refactor/rename original app.ts to application.ts - the generated files (.js and .map) will be updated accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Some links you may find useful:

http://igorzelmanovich.blogspot.ru/2013/01/converting-existing-javascript-code-to.html

[Is there a tool to convert JavaScript files to TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412164/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-javascript-files-to-typescript)

http://stackful-dev.com/typescript-nodejs-vim-and-linux-oh-my